# Images won't allign on one row in bootsrap 3

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently setting up a bootstrap website using a template, I have a logo that has quite a large width, someone has told me that it is better to split it up into 3 separate images to make them more responsive as the name of the company is "Straight Talking Solutions". I have split up the image, and when I place them into the website, they just stack on top of each other, I have tried to make the images smaller, but no luck. I have also tried them with and without the `.img-responsive` class. I would attach a screen shot but I can't sorry. Thanks in advance, Dan.

Html Code Here

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 logo">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
        <img alt="logo" title="straight talking solutions" src="img/STS/straight.png" class=""/>
        <img alt="logo" title="straight talking solutions" src="img/STS/talking.png" class=""/>
        <img alt="logo" title="straight talking solutions" src="img/STS/solutions.png" class="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Css

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: We need more information. Post your HTML and CSS in your post please.

Comment: Do you want the border to be around all 3 images or around each one individually?

Comment: You probably did not need to split the images... also your html does not have img-responsive class

Comment: I want the border around all of them. @LeoJweda

Comment: Yeah @Huangism I had taken it out and forgot to add it in.

Comment: @Huangism I tried the non split image, but it came up too small

Answer (score 0):

change css to:

```
.logo img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}
```

OR

```
.logo {
  font-size: 0;
}

.logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the font-size:0 if you take out the white spaces between each img tag

Answer (score 0):

To add a border around all 3 images (still waiting for clarification), just apply `.responsive` which is included in Bootstrap to the div. Then you just need to make sure to add `display:inline-block;` to the individual images to place them next to each other.

Comment: I can think of a few things that can cause that to not work. Unfortunately without more details about your code I can't eliminate enough of them and listing them all is too tedious.